# How do I replace MFC CDailog::OnTimer with ATL CAxDialogImpl method?

Tags: timer, mfc, atl

I had wrote a `CMyDailog` with MFC based on `CDialog`. And there is a `OnTimer` method override the `CDialog` one.

```
CMyDailog : public CDialog
{
    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
}
```

Now, we are migrating our MFC code to ATL. I have to make `CMyDailog` inherited from `CAxDialogImpl<CMyDailog>`.

```
CMyDailog : public CAxDialogImpl<CMyDailog>
{}
```

I didn't find an equivalent of `CDialog::OnTimer` in the ATL side. Do I have to use the Windows API `::SetTimer(GolbalTimerFunction)` to achive that? In that case, I have to move my original member variable values into the globe scope -- I don't like that.

I find this maybe help:
https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2870588/what-is-the-event-i-should-use.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the equivalent one.

```
LRESULT OnTimer(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
```

[For more detail](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?102440-ATL-and-SetTimer)